# How to know the source Provider from Location using Google Location Services

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-play-services

I am using Google Play's Location Services http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html

for location requirement, everything seem to be working as expected. I am setting the priority for Power Balance mode, which as per the documentation will provide the GPS points from Network or WIFI with lesser impact on battery.
On callback to `onLocationChanged()` I don't seem to figure out what is the source provider for the location I got. My requirement needs me to figure this out.
However, there are ways we can make assumptions about the source, I just wanted to check if anyone else have figured it out?

Thanks,
SKU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Play Location API does not provide a way to determine the source provider as it functions as a [Fused Location Provider](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html):

> The Fused Location Provider intelligently manages the underlying location technology and gives you the best location according to your needs.

The location returned may be a combination of cellular, WiFi, GPS, and/or sensor data.

Comment: I did not notice this before, but Location object received on "onLocationChanged()" has getProvider(). Do you think this should help my purpose?

Comment: @ianhanniballake does this mean that `lat` might be GPS based and `lng` WiFi based in one Location object? I noticed that I can only trust GPS and have to alter accuracy value for cell based locations. Fused says a fix is 100m accurate when in reality is 1000m accurate. That's why I ask this question.

Comment: @GregDan - yes, a single `Location` can contain data from multiple sources. If it says it is 100m accurate, then it believes based on combined data from WiFi, GPS, and sensor data that you are indeed within 100m of the returned `Location`.